# How to find a string and append a (unsafe) text?

Tags: sed, sh

I'm trying to make a autoconf script to append a text after variables in Makefile (e.g. $(CFLAGS) -> $(CFLAGS) -Inside). And sed doesn't work since my string could have a "/" and other uncontrolled chars.

The goal is just, after each match of A, append text B without doing any processing on it.

I have tried `sed -e "s/\$(CFLAGS)/& {r put.CFLAGS}/g"` where `put.CFLAGS` contain the content to append, but it directly append `{r put.CFLAGS}` without reading the file.

How can I do this ?

Comment: This looks like [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You can do this, but there's almost certainly a better way. Maybe adding a line ("CFLAGS += -Inside") or having your makefile(s) `include` the parameter file.

Answer (score 0):

Night give good hint.

I have achieve what I want by using escape sequences.
First I replace unsafe chars with escape sequence, in my case I use `sed 's/\//\\\\057/g;s/&/\\\\046/g'` that convert &->\046 and /->\057 (to just got \057 and \046, use `sed 's/\//\\057/g;s/&/\\046/g'`).

Then printf will revert escaped char to original meaning.

```
for i in $MAKEVAR_LIST; do
  SED_ARG="`printf "$RAW" | sed 's/\//\\\\057/g;s/&/\\\\046/g'`"
cat "vache.makoge" | sed -e "s/\$($i)/& $SED_ARG/g" > "veau.makoge"
mv -f "veau.makoge" "vache.makoge"
done
```

Where :

- `RAW` contain the unsafe thing append
- `MAKEVAR_LIST` a list of vars where append `RAW`
- `vache.makoge` the final Makefile

It's dirty but this work for me.